# Add Excel column without breaking equation

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have completed a very complex Excel spreadsheet with a lot of equations, except I forgot to include September.

I have January through December, all the months, *except* the calculations for September. Of course all the equations are currently perfect for the data that's here.

How do I add a whole new column without ruining the previous equations?

Comment: Otherwise, simply insert a whole new column, it won't ruin your equations.  Have you tried this yet?

Comment: Unless your complex spreadsheet is using indirect cell referencing, when you insert the new column your existing formulas should automatically adjust.